# Cannot use relative path for styleUrls in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have below file structure:

```
/src/
  app/
  components/
    block/
      block.html
      block.scss
      block.ts
      sub-block.ts
```

The sub-block is a component which inherits block component and share the same html file and scss file:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sub-block',
    templateUrl: 'block.html',
    styleUrls: ['./block.scss'],
})
export class SubBlockComponent extends BlockComponent{...}
```

When I run app, it reports error:

```
 GET http://localhost:8100/block.scss 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried

- styleUrls: ['block.scss']
- styleUrls: ['./block.scss']
- styleUrls: ['/src/components/block/bock.scss']
- styleUrls: ['src/components/block/bock.scss']
- styleUrls: ['../components/block/bock.scss']

All failed.

How can I get it work?  Is that revelant to tsconfig or webpack?

Comment: Have you tried ['block.scss']?

Comment: @GerryMcBride yes, I tried.

Comment: I found: even if there is no sub-block, the styleUrls doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're are experiencing this bug? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4974
In your case the solution may be to just remove the `styleUrls` declaration line (a comment in the bug issue suggests this).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure your `baseUrl` is configured in your `tsconfig.json`. That could be why it can't find the file.

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: my tsconfig is “baseUrl”: "."

Answer (score 0):

Created a stackblitz with the block and sub-block components, able to use same HTML and SCSS in both places https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkhz8b

Comment: Your example on stackblitz is not working. I changed block.scss to any name, it still reports no error.